# WSO2 IoT 3.0.0 cannot started in mac

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I try to start  WSO2 IoT 3.0.0 server on macOS it's stuck like below. However I was using the old version and it has been working like a charm.

- Another note: me deployment server is : windows server 2012, WSO2 IoT 3.0.0 server works successfully, but I can not access devicemgt link, it's redirect me to black page.

https://localhost:9443/devicemgt/uuf/login?referer=/

--------------------- Update -------------------- 
FYI: carbon works like a charm 
https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp

`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
[2017-02-10 19:37:36,170] [IoT-Core]  INFO - AppDiscoveryComponent WebApp Discovery component activated
[2017-02-10 19:37:36,317] [IoT-Core]  INFO - AppManagerMobileComponent WSO2MDM_INTERNAL MDM is bound to App Manager.
[2017-02-10 19:37:36,317] [IoT-Core]  INFO - AppManagerMobileComponent App Manger Mobile Component activated.
[2017-02-10 19:37:36,456] [IoT-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2017-02-10 19:37:36,457] [IoT-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Operating System : Mac OS X 10.12.2, x86_64
[2017-02-10 19:37:36,457] [IoT-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Home        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
[2017-02-10 19:37:36,458] [IoT-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Version     : 1.8.0_111
[2017-02-10 19:37:36,458] [IoT-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.111-b14,Oracle Corporation
[2017-02-10 19:37:36,458] [IoT-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Carbon Home      : /Volumes/WorkSpace/ParentApp/wso2iot-3.0.0/core
[2017-02-10 19:37:36,459] [IoT-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Temp Dir    : /Volumes/WorkSpace/ParentApp/wso2iot-3.0.0/core/tmp
[2017-02-10 19:37:36,460] [IoT-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator User             : root, en-US, Asia/Kuala_Lumpur
[2017-02-10 19:37:36,620] [IoT-Core]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter Swap Memory size (MB): 1024 of the system is below the recommended minimum size :2047
[2017-02-10 19:37:36,621] [IoT-Core]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter Carbon is configured to use the default keystore (wso2carbon.jks). To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
Activating org.wso2.jaggery.scxml with RealmService enabled
[2017-02-10 19:37:54,558] [IoT-Core]  INFO - TaglibUriRule TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined`

Comment: Is this happening in the vanilla pack? I have seen similar behaviors if there are connection failures to databases. If you are not running the vanilla pack or modified the datasources with an external database, please check the database connection from the server running node.

Comment: this is not clear, how should I check the database connection, I followed the tutorial, but there is noting regards to the DB ! , please check my update

Answer (score 1):

What is the version of your OS, are you using Sierra or above? if so you may want to have a look at your /etc/host configurations, as host resolution is known to cause this type of problems.

Please have a look at :

https://medium.com/@ruwanyatawara/how-to-fix-macos-sierra-wso2-server-starting-delay-4279b9e69133

Comment: If possible you should add the basics of the solution to your answer. Sometimes links go dead and, so, might not be available to people with this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same issue sometimes back when updated into Sierra 10.12. Also tried changing the /etc/hosts as mentioned in the other answer. Following worked for me. First try following commands;

```
sudo scutil --get ComputerName
sudo scutil --get LocalHostName
sudo scutil --get HostName
```

Above commands would return the current values assigned. If one of the above didn't output anything try adding new host names with the followings;

```
sudo scutil --set ComputerName "Rasika’s MacBook Pro"
sudo scutil --set LocalHostName "Rasikas-MacBook-Pro"
sudo scutil --set HostName "Rasikas-MacBook-Pro"
```

Then try starting the IoT Server.